# Angular ng-click toggles when clicked second time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to figure simplest implementation for having a button using ng-click to toggle if a user selects it a second time and then back if they click a third time. Basically, what I have now is using a ng-click with a ng-show with 4 different buttons, An example is shown below and it works, but my requirement now is that if the user selects the button again, it unshows the div below. Didn't think it was good practice using ng-show and ng-hide together for this and cannot see how ng-toggle would work. Any help please?

The sample code:

```
<div id="alerts">
    <div class="alertBtns">
        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow =2" value="outstanding swipes">
        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow =3" value="recent denials">
        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow =4" value="upcoming dates">
        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow =5" value="account alerts">
    </div>
    <div class="alertGrids">
        <div ng-show="alertShow==1"></div>
        <div ng-show="alertShow==2">
        </div>
        <div ng-show="alertShow==3" class="alertDenials">
        </div>
        <div ng-show="alertShow==4" class="alertDates">
        </div>
        <div ng-show="alertShow==5" class="alertAccounts">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value according to the current value of `alertShow`. Example:

```
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)" value="outstanding swipes">
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 3 ? -1 : 3)" value="recent denials">
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)" value="upcoming dates">
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 5 ? -1 : 5)" value="account alerts">
```

If you try to click on the same button again, the value of `alertShow` become **-1**.

Comment: I have in my controller for it to be set to 1 to start with simply: $scope.showAlert = 1; So if doing this in controller, I want to default to 1 on page load and then any button, once clicked again, pushes state back to 1 rather than -1, so am thinking it would be minus that as I want it to go back to? And in turn, need the appropriate number, but then do I need further scope in controller for this rather than the one?

Comment: $scope.showAlert = 1 = showAlert == 2 ? -1 : 2;    but hangup is adding the different ones in this same scope.